# Regular Expression on Yesod type Text

Tags: haskell, yesod, hackage

Currently, I am changing my Text to String then using Text.Regex.Posix to do my matching.  Is there a idiomatic and efficient way to do regular expression in Yesod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the [regex-tdfa-text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-tdfa-text) package? It provides backend support for using the `regex-base` library with `Text` strings.