# Yesod Regular Expressions in 2019

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack

Yesod uses `Text` a lot.

I wish to use any Regex library at all, that supports UTF8 and `Text`.

The most-recommended two libraries seem to be:

- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-tdfa
- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-pcre

**Attempts at regex-tdfa:**

```
import          Text.Regex.TDFA
...
let (parta,partb,partc) = ((sometext :: Text) =~ ("de" :: String)) :: (String, String, String)
```

I can't seem to use `Text`, even though it appears that `regex-tdfa` has some sort of module for `Text` 
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-tdfa-1.3.1.0/docs/Text-Regex-TDFA-Text.html

The version of regex-tdfa that stack has installed here is regex-tdfa-1.2.3.1 and it won't use the newer one that has the above Text.Regex.TDFA.Text, for some reason. When I try to specify the version `- regex-tdfa >=1.3.1` in my package.yaml, I get this error when building with "yesod devel":

```
In the dependencies for example-0.0.0(+dev +library-only):
    regex-tdfa-1.2.3.1 from stack configuration does not match >=1.3.1 
needed since backend is a build target.
```

Existing SO question: The answer to this question is out of date, regex-tdfa-text is deprecated:
[Regular Expression on Yesod type Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160216/regular-expression-on-yesod-type-text)

How can I use the `Text`-supporting version of regex-tdfa?

**Attempts with PCRE:**

```
import          Text.Regex.PCRE
...
let stringResult = ( "hello there" :: Text ) =~ ( "e" :: Text ) :: AllTextMatches [] Text
```

This doesn't work unless I replace all the `Text` with `String`.
The error is:

```
  • No instance for (RegexMaker Regex CompOption ExecOption Text)
        arising from a use of ‘=~’
    • In the expression:
          ("hello there" :: Text) =~ ("e" :: Text) :: AllTextMatches [] Text
```

This tutorial claims PCRE works with UTF8: https://gabebw.com/blog/2015/10/11/regular-expressions-in-haskell

But I am not sure if regex-pcre claims to work with `Text`. Am I supposed to convert from `Text` to `String` and then use regex-pcre?

**Summary:**

What is the best practice for using regex with Yesod? How can I use a library with `Text` AND UTF8?

Comment: If you specify `regex-tdfa >=1.3.1`, then you ask for a `regex-tdfa` library with a version that is `1.3.1` or higher. But as you say yourself, the library installed `regex-tdfa-1.2.3.1` hence the error.

Comment: Yes, exactly; I ask for it. I think that package.yaml and stack are supposed to manage what is installed. I would like to tell stack to use the version that's on hackage, not stackage? Stackage does not go up to that number yet, except for in "nightly" https://www.stackage.org/lts-14.17/package/regex-tdfa-1.2.3.2 Can I specify nightly just for that one package? I can't find it in the docs unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the error message about the dependency, you should see the following text displayed:

```
Some different approaches to resolving this:

  * Set 'allow-newer: true' in /u/buhr/.stack/config.yaml to ignore all version
    constraints and build anyway.

  * Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps 
    .../yesodtest/stack.yaml:

- regex-tdfa-1.3.1.0@sha256:c77808a0d68d275c75fb84dc9ced340536574...
```

The `extra-deps` solution is the preferred one.  In your project-specific `stack.yaml`, add:

```
extra-deps:
- regex-tdfa-1.3.1.0
```

(The detailed SHA256 is not actually needed.)  This throws another error because `regex-base` is too old, so you need to also add it, as per the recommended action:

```
extra-deps:
- regex-tdfa-1.3.1.0
- regex-base-0.94.0.0
```

That was enough to get a `yesod/simple` template building for me using `resolver: lts-14.17`.